# MongoDB Command Line Query db.Collection.find().pretty() Not Working

Tags: mongodb

I've read the documentation about query to load data in mongodb database. What I've done :

1. Open Command Line (Windows)
2. Start Mongod and Mongo
3. use first_test
4. db.table1.insert({"Column 1":"Data 1"})

Then I try `db.table1.find().pretty()` But The result not return as it must be like in documentation. Is there anything wrong in my command line or something else ?

Comment: Did you get this response ( WriteResult({"nInserted":1}) ) from mongodb server after the insert?

Comment: Yes, I Got It.`db.table1.find()` work fine. Just with pretty() in the bottom of code that make me confused, why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your document has to have at least 3 fields to be prettyfied